# Infinite loop with okta and react-persist

Tags: reactjs, okta, okta-api

I created a react application using the package `'@okta/okta-react'` and everything is (was…) ok.
I added `'react-persist'` to my project and now I have an infinite loop of redirects from the homepage to the `/implicit/callback` route with the error

`Unable to retrieve OAuth redirect params cookie`

I tried to blacklist ‘auth’ on my persist configuration, like this:

```
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  blacklist: ['auth']
}
```

but the issue is still there. any idea?